dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe) Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-compu
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-compute-535_53
5.183.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_arm64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so', which is also in
package nvidia-l4t-cuda 35.5.0-20240219203809
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-utils-535_535.183.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_arm64.deb
...
Unpacking nvidia-utils-535 (535.183.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-utils-535_535.183
.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_arm64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/nvidia-xconfig', which is also in package nvidia
-l4t-x11 35.5.0-20240219203809
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-compute-535_535.183.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_arm6
4.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-utils-535_535.183.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_arm64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Hi Guys idk what the issue is, I tried to uninstall no success, this has been blocking my new pip installs
To get rid of the error and be able to install
